# Importing from CSV into LanguageText

Tags: c#, csv, localization, umbraco7

Is there any way to import values from a CSV column and place them in the LanguageText database table using Umbraco's LocalizationService? Basically I have a bunch of button Dictionary items i.e. "submit_button", "bootstrap_button" etc.. but I want to have the translations for each i.e. "שלח" with each language, but I seem to have to do it manually, can anyone give me any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36894163/5971639 This is the conclusion I came to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this Umbraco package?

https://github.com/hfloyd/DictionaryDashboardForUmbraco

It looks as though it can help you import/export dictionary items, but via XML. If nothing else, maybe some of the source code can give you a starting point to use CSV instead?

https://github.com/hfloyd/DictionaryDashboardForUmbraco/blob/master/src/DictionaryDashboard/Usercontrols/import.ascx.cs

Comment: You should point to whatever answer/solution you found - plus accept an answer or close the question entirely, I think.